# How Do I make S3 links download not stream?

Tags: amazon-s3

I have been trying to get this link below to download but it keeps streaming. Have tried setting the content disposition to attachment but does not seem to help. I want people to get it as a download. Help! Thanks.

https://s3-ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/anahata/Guided+Relaxation.mp3

Answer (score 0):

You should also set the `Content-Type` to something like `application/octet-stream`

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty old question, but I hope it can help someone. You can add the query argument "response-content-disposition" = "attachment; filename=some-file.txt".

You can find more info/help in the AWS documentation: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectGET.html.

Additionaly, if you are using the ruby sdk, it would be something like this:

```
s3_object.url_for(:read, expires: expiration_date, response_content_disposition: 'attachment; filename=some-file.txt')
```